# Check if wrapped Python function is callable like a function

Tags: python, dask

This is a Python function

```
def inc(x):
    return x + 1

x = 1
```

`isinstance` function Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

```
>>> isinstance(inc, types.FunctionType)
True
```

Although `isinstance` does not work when checking the Function inside a wrapper.

```
>>> from dask import delayed

>>> isinstance(delayed(inc), types.FunctionType)
False
>>> isinstance(delayed(inc)(x), types.FunctionType)
True
```

## Question

Is there a way to check a Python function inside a wrapper?

Comment: Just keep a reference to the wrapped function and check it? But what are you trying to achieve here? You can pass any callable to `delayed`, not only instances of `FunctionType`. And if it is not a callable you will know anyway but you'd better check it before calling `delayed`on it if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

Many, but not all, decorators return a `FunctionType`.  When you wrap a function in the `@delayed` decorator, it does not return a function; it [returns a class instance (object) of `Delayed`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/696a74a8d4d72c1d16b22c1c41a57f0729a3a513/dask/delayed.py#L224).

For this reason, you might want [`callable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) here rather than the more specific `types.FunctionType`:

```
>>> from dask import delayed
>>> def inc(x):
...     return x + 1
... 
>>> callable(inc)
True
>>> callable(delayed(inc))
True
```

`callable()` is in some regards a "broader" check than `isinstance(..., types.FunctionType`, because a pure function is not the only thing that is callable.  An instance of a class that defines `.__call__()` is as well.  The class `Delayed` [does indeed define `.__call__()`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/696a74a8d4d72c1d16b22c1c41a57f0729a3a513/dask/delayed.py#L537), so it fits the bill here.